# How to benchmark a performance core on an M1/M2 Pro

Tags: performance, apple-silicon, benchmark

I'm running some compiler tests and I noticed that as I ran more iterations per run, the average time *increased* and the standard deviation increased (which should have decreased as random variations averaged out). What I realized was that a test started out on a performance core, but as it ran longer, it got scheduled onto an efficiency core.

So my question is how to get a terminal task to run entirely on a performance core. This is on an M2 Pro Macbook